# Linq to SQL: Equivalent of Array.SequenceEqual

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

Let's say I have this method:

```
public T GetByID(object[] pKeys)
{
    DbQuery<T> dbq = mContext.GetDbSet<T>();
    return dbq.SingleOrDefault(ent => ent.PrimaryKey.SequenceEqual(pKeys));
}
```

`ent.PrimaryKey` is an `object[]`.

Of course, this doesn't work because of the `SequenceEqual()`. I could maybe use `Contains` but this would not preserve order: {1, 2} is NOT equal to {2, 1}.

I could also use `AsEnumerable()` first and then use some logics but that would load the whole table in memory, which is unacceptable.

Is there a way to achieve this?

**Edit**

I've made the method generic. Because that's what it really is and it makes more sens with the primary key being an array.

I also point out that the goal of the method here could be achieved with mContext.GetDbSet().Find(pKeys). This, however, complicates the use of `dbq.Include(property)` or `mContext.Entry(wanted).Collection(property).Load()` for parent.child properties which is another matter not related to the question.

Comment: I suppose there is no way to use any kind of SequenceEqual in Linq to Sql. But why you use object[] as PrimaryKey? The object[] length is not fixed?

Comment: This is a simplified version of a generic method used for all our entities. The primary keys are sometimes composite.

Answer (score 0):

Without reproducible code it is a little tough to test any particular solution, but the first thing that came to my mind (and compiled/tested in notepad) is

```
public T GetByID(object[] pKeys)
{
    DbQuery<T> dbq = mContext.GetDbSet<T>();

    for (var i = 0; i < pKeys.length; i++)
    {
        dbq = dbq.Where(ent => ent.PrimaryKey[i] == pKeys[i]);
    }

    return dbq.SingleOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: Won't work, it throws the exception "The LINQ expression node type 'ArrayIndex' is not supported in LINQ to Entities."

The GetDbSet<T>() just returns the DbSet for the matching generic type. you could replace all generic stuff with a particular type. See original (unedited) question

Comment: Is there anything I could add to make this reproducible code?